# Specifying Default Value in Insert Statement - Does It Matter In Term Of Performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a simple table, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tab 
(
    Column1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Column2 DATETIME CONSTRAINT DF_tab_Column2 DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Does the `INSERT` statement makes any performance difference in the following queries? Does specifying the `default` value matter?

Q1:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tab (Column1)
VALUES ('ABC');
```

Q2:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tab (Column1, Column2)
VALUES ('ABC', GETDATE());
```

Comment: Have you run them with execution plans and compared?

Comment: Compare the query plan.

Comment: I still better ask in case there exists some rare case where the plans differ. Or if it depends on certain condition(s) e,g. number of columns and number of default constraints specified.

Answer (score 0):

**No** it Doesn't,

There is no Difference between them depends on `Execution Plan`

[image]